# Replace Function with Backslash in Snowflake

Tags: replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why does the query

```
select replace('its a\b\c\d','\\\\','\\\\\\\\')
```

give the result `'its acd'` while executed in Snowflake

where as the other SQL compiler produces the result `'its a\b\c\d'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Escape Sequences](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#escape-sequences):

> Within a single-quoted string constant, a single quote character, along with other special characters, can alternatively be included in escape sequences. A backslash character (`\`) begins a backslash escape sequence.
>
> **Note that a non-special character escaped with a backslash is simply interpreted as that character (e.g. '\z' becomes 'z').**

The string:

```
SELECT 'its a\b\c\d', '\\', '\\\\'
=>
its a<BS>cd, '\', '\\'

SELECT '\a', '\c', '\d'
=>
a, c, d
```

The symbol `\b` is **the backspace character.**

```
SELECT ASCII('\b');
=> 8
```

The REPLACE is trying to replace `\`(which does not existing in the input string) with `\\` and it is a reason why it returns: `its a<BS>cd`

---

To perform the replacement the dollar-quoting could be used:

```
SELECT $$its a\b\c\d$$, $$\$$, $$\\$$;
=>
its a\\b\\c\\d
```